# Confirm password custom directive is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to implement confirm password validation in angular view. write new

directive in app.js

[image]

and  add `compare-to` in confirm password text box

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Enter password"
                   ng-model="Password"
                   ng-minlength="5">

            <span class="validationMessage" ng-show="frm.password.$dirty && frm.password.$error.required">Required!</span>
            <span class="validationMessage" ng-show="frm.password.$dirty && frm.password.$error.minlength">Min length 5!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Confirm Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password"
                   class="form-control"
                   ng-model="ConfirmPassword"
                   required
                   compare-to="Password"
                   placeholder="Enter Confirm password">

            <span class="validationMessage" ng-show="frm.ConfirmPassword.$error">Required!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the confirm password is not shows any validation. and show a error message **Cannot set property 'compareTo' of undefined** in chrome.

[image]

Comment: Would be good to have code in text format or a plunker/fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. But i have no experience about this code sandbox.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. I will update the status very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working, mostly. You just have little logic flaws there.

First of all, using `<label for="x">` expects template to have a element with `id="x"` present. Nothing major there but when you check for `form` validity you should refer to your form fields, not underlying model.

So instead of `frm.<ng-model-var>.$error` you should type in `frm.<form-field-name>.$error`.

You need to add names for your inputs, and check your form validation logic once more. This should work fine for your `password`.

```
<!-- added required, input name, changed validation logic -->
<input type="password" 
       name="password"
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Enter password" 
       ng-model="Password" 
       required 
       ng-minlength="5" />
<span class="validationMessage" 
      ng-show="frm.password.$error.required">
  Required!
</span>
<span class="validationMessage" 
      ng-show="frm.password.$dirty && frm.password.$error.minlength">
  Min length 5!
</span>
```

and this for your `confirm password`.

```
<!-- added input name, changed validation logic -->
<input type="password"
       name="confirmpassword"
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Enter Confirm password"
       ng-model="ConfirmPassword" 
       required 
       compare-to="Password" />
<span class="validationMessage" 
      ng-show="frm.password.$valid && frm.confirmpassword.$invalid">
  Passwords do not match!
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with updated versions

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js

and in your `controller.js` add this..

```
'ngRoute'
var loginApp = angular.module('indexApp', ['authModule','requestModule','ngRoute']);
```